# Cast IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,object>> to a single merged Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

First of all, I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Bag
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have the larger Dictionary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> allBags = ParseLinesIntoBags(lines);
```

Now I want to get a Dictionary of the same type as the upper one, but with the condition that the List<Bag> must contain a specific name (in my case "shiny gold"). For the further clarification if the allBags has the following:

```
 { "black", new List<Bag>() {new Bag("red", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
 { "yellow", new List<Bag>() {new Bag("shiny gold", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
 { "pink", new List<Bag>() { new Bag("blue", 2), new Bag("shiny gold", 3), new Bag("green", 4) } }
```

the other Dictionary therefore should have:

```
{ "yellow", new List<Bag>() {new Bag("shiny gold", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
{ "pink", new List<Bag>() { new Bag("blue", 2), new Bag("shiny gold", 3), new Bag("green", 4) } }
```

. The task which I'm solving is from AdventOfCode2020 day 7 ([LINK](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/7)).

**EDIT**: (*since the original didn't follow the standards. I also deleted my failed tries because they were too far from the solution, and would only result in additional confusion*.)

So currently I have the following code (Special thanks to @AliReza for coming with an almost full solution):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace Day7
{
    public class Bag
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public Bag(string name, int number)
        {
            Name = name;
            Number = number;
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> allBags = new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>(){
                { "black", new List<Bag>() {new Bag("red", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
                { "yellow", new List<Bag>() {new Bag("shiny gold", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
                { "pink", new List<Bag>() { new Bag("blue", 2), new Bag("shiny gold", 3), new Bag("green", 4) } }};
            string condition = "shiny gold";
            var containerBagsV =from item in allBags
                                from bag in item.Value
                                where bag.Name == condition
                                select new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>() { { item.Key, item.Value.ToList() } };
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder now is there any way to strongly type the Dictionary insted of leaving it to var? If I change var to Dictionary<string, List> immidietly

```
Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> containerBagsV = from item in allBags
                                from bag in item.Value
                                where bag.Name == condition
                                select new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>() { { item.Key, item.Value.ToList() } };
```

I get the following compile error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
> System.Collections.Generic.List<Day7.Bag>>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
> System.Collections.Generic.List<Day7.Bag>>'. An explicit conversion
> exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I try to cast it

```
Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> containerBagsV = (Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>)(from item in allBags
                                from bag in item.Value
                                where bag.Name == condition
                                select new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>() { { item.Key, item.Value.ToList() } });
```

I get the following exception:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type

> 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Day7.Bag]],Day7.Bag],System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Day7.Bag]]]'
> to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Day7.Bag]]'.'

Comment: _"it has errors"_ is not a useful problem statement. Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68431718/edit) and fix the problems with it, including the lack of the _complete_ details of whatever error you are getting, the lack of a proper [mcve], and the lack of a clear, detailed explanation of what you've done so far to try to fix the problem and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Going by your edited question, I think what you are looking for is (delete the line with containerBagsV):
`var filteredDict = allBags.Where(x => x.Value.Any(bag => bag.Name == condition)).ToDictionary(y => y.Key);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should get the idea with this example

```cs
    var allBags = new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>
    {
        { "black", new List<Bag>()  { new Bag("red", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
        { "yellow", new List<Bag>() { new Bag("shiny gold", 1), new Bag("blue", 2) } },
        { "pink", new List<Bag>() { new Bag("blue", 2), new Bag("shiny gold", 3), new Bag("green", 4) } }
    };
    
    var containerBag = from item in allBags
                       from bag in item.Value
                       where bag.Name == "shiny gold"
                       select item;
 // this return yellow and pink records, you can select bag here also if you want
```

also if you want a dictionary output :

```cs
var containerBag = from item in allBags
                       from bag in item.Value
                       where bag.Name == "shiny gold"
                       select new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>>() { { item.Key, item.Value.ToList() } };
```

---

UPDATE
merged version :

```cs
var containerBag = from item in allBags
                       from bag in item.Value
                       where bag.Name == "shiny gold"
                       select item;   

Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> mergedDictionary = new(containerBag);
```

Comment: While this basiclly solves my problem, is there any way to strong type my Dictionary or it must stay as var? When I put Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> insted of var it does not let me compille (error CS0266), and if I cast it I also get the similar error

Comment: you can not do that because the return object is not a single dictionary (for example above sample returns 2 dictionaries) so it's an `IEnumerable of you dictionary`. but you can merge both dictionaries into one if you want.

Comment: I've added a merged dictionary example. @LukaMrko.
if you are not using c# 9 > change `new(containerBag)` to `new Dictionary<string, List<Bag>> (containerBag)`